# PHP - exec() not working how I want it to

Tags: php, html, exec

```
<html>                                                                                                                                
<head>                                                                                                                                
<title>Yep.avi</title>                                                                                                                
</head>                                                                                                                               
<body>                                                                                                                                
    <form action="bruh.php" method="post">                                                                                            
       <input type="text" name="cmdsendsrv" value="Classcode">                                                                        
       <br>                                                                                                                           
       <input type="submit" name="hello" value="Connect">                                                                             
    </form>                                                                                                                           
</body>                                                                                                                               
</html>
```

So the above code seems setup correctly and that is my index.php so now moving on to the bruh.php

```
<html>                                                                                                                                
<body>                                                                                                                                
<article>                                                                                                                             
<?php                                                                                                                                 
    if (isset($_POST[hello])) {                                                                                                       
        exec('export GOPATH=/usr/lib/golang/src/');                                                                                   
        exec('go run /usr/lib/golang/src/src/github.com/julbaby/kek/crash.go ' .$_POST['cmdsendsrv'],' trucklover123');               
        sleep(3);                                                                                                                     
        echo "Joined leaving in 60 seconds";                                                                                          
        sleep(60);                                                                                                                    
        exec('pkill go');                                                                                                             
        echo "Done!";                                                                                                                 
        }                                                                                                                             
        ?>                                                                                                                            
</article>                                                                                                                            
</body>                                                                                                                               
</html>
```

Now I am simply wondering why is this not working? Like, I have looked at it a bunch and I dont see any errors and I have been attempting this for over 3 hours I feel like im making a silly mistake please help <3

Comment: change $_POST[hello] to $_POST['hello'];

Comment: if hello is a variable you must attach $ with that if it is something else write it in single or double code

Comment: @saty Do I need the ; too or just the ' ?

Comment: you use  if (isset($_POST["hello"])) {   and try

Comment: Still not working im wondering if it could be something else too... Could it be that it doesnt like me getting the .$_POST['cmdsendsrv'] also I did find something else I think I am running apache as root so could that be another problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem relies in the following line:

```
if (isset($_POST[hello])) {
```

Should be:

```
if (isset($_POST["hello"])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that apache has permissions to whatever file or folder you are trying to access. See how my public_html folder belongs to the apache group?

```
drwxrwxr-x. 39 apache       apache       4.0K Apr 23 09:39 public_html
```

Before you change ownership of the file/folder, make sure your user belongs to the apache group as well.

Comment: I just got on to my logs using tail -f /etc/httpd/logs/error_log and I figured it out but i do need help still how do I switch .$_POST['cmdsendsrv'] to just be like $somethinghere cuz here is my logs `PHP Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /var/www/html/bruh.php on line 7, referer: `

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Where is $somethinghere defined? What is the purpose? Are you trying to create a variable called $somethinghere and assign it the value of $_POST['cmdsendsrv']?

Comment: Yes sorry here is what I have now `<html>
<body>
<article>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["hello"])) {
        $classcode = $_POST['cmdsendsrv'];
        exec('export GOPATH=/usr/lib/golang/src/');
        exec('go run /usr/lib/golang/src/src/github.com/julbaby/kek/crash.go ' $classcode,' trucklover123');
        sleep(3);
        echo "Joined leaving in 60 seconds";
        sleep(60);
        exec('pkill go');
        echo "Done!";
        }
        ?>
</article>
</body>
</html>` I am getting unexpected T_VARIABLE on the line that I added $classcode

Comment: Is $classcode a part of your exec string? Is 'trucklover123' also a part of the string or is it the 2nd parameter you're passing to exec?

Comment: Okay i actually have it working but the whole sleep thing is absolutely hated by the  php lol so what im gonna do is add in a stop button on the index page as it doesnt redirect due to the sleeps that will pkill go thanks guys :D

Comment: Can you share what you did? Also, what makes you think the sleep function is hated by php?

Comment: idk the second I removed it, it was working but there is one issue how would I keep the script running forever? Like I want it to run until I pkill go so any chance you know how? :P Also when it 100% works Ill post source :D